# What is protocol I can use for connection?

Tags: java, tcp

What is port I can use for someone can connect me and get message connection is established ?

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"),true);
            printWriter.println("Connection is established");
```

Thank you

Comment: Please also post the code of the client.

Comment: There isn't client code I have written very simple example)

Comment: below you mention "the client didn't get message". How are we supposed to know what the problem is?

Comment: I need to know only port number for connection.Can I use any port or in strict range ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Deny

The port is for you (the server) to decide.
The client needs to know what port to connect to, so it can get a response.

Comment: I had done 9990 and the client didn't get message

Comment: Since we haven't seen your client code, how can we comment on it? You should create a [mre] so that we can compile and run both your client and server so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, just don't pick some port that currently your computer is using will be fine. Such as like 20 or 80, those ports are using in real http data transferring

In the below codes, your can notice that I just randomly pick a port, to note that, both ports in sender and receiver have to be the same, otherwise, you will not get the message.
This one is TCPSender.py

```
from socket import *

serverName = 'localhost'

serverPort = 8797

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))

sentence = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')

clientSocket.send(sentence)

modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print ('From Server:', modifiedSentence)

clientSocket.close()
```

This one is TCP Receiver.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 8797
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

print ('The server is ready to receive')

while 1:
     connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

     sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    
     print(sentence)

     capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()

     connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence)

     connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: Btw, the example I gave is based on python, but I am sure the codes help you make understanding in Java tho, if you like it, I hope you can tip me some reputation, I am earning them right now

Comment: Good port numbers to use
Ports 1024-49151- Registered Port -These can be registered for services with the IANA and should be treated as semi-reserved. User written programs should not use these ports. Ports 49152-65535– These are used by client programs and you are free to use these in client programs.